# Heron 1.0.5 - can't use measurelength tool

Tags: javascript, heron-mapping-client

When looking at the examples of Heron v1.0.5 it looks like I simply have to include a simple `{type: "measurelength", options: {geodesic: true}}` for the toolbar and an even more simple `{type: "measurepanel"}` for the bottombar. However, that doesn't work.

I am using a similar layout to the one in the [FixedPanelLayout](http://lib.heron-mc.org/heron/1.0.5/examples/fixedpanelslayout/index.html) and I do have the same problem as it is prominent in the [NoStatusBar](http://lib.heron-mc.org/heron/1.0.5/examples/nostatusbar/index.html) example.

If you try to use the 'Measure length' tool in the latter link you will face the same error that I get in my application.

Does anybody know how to overcome the problem and have the measured length in the toolbar (bbar)?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens? Can you give an image to show the result, or the error messages?